# Subscription type in iOS in-App-Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription

I have a question about what type of iOS subscription I may use according to our project. In summary, my app is intended to personal trainers in order to control the sport efficiency of different team players. Every personal trainer can create up to 3 players for free, but if they want more than 3 players, they have to pay. I want to offer the possibility of choosing the number of players they want and pay 7€ each approximately.

I would like to use autorenewal subscriptions, but is awkward to create around 100 products in order to offer up to 100 players. Is possible to let the user buy the same subscription as many times as the user wants? Which could be the best option for our issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No, a subscription product can only be purchased once (per period). You might want to consider using "tiers" to reduce the number of products you need to create; e.g. 5 players, 10 players, 20 players and so on

Comment: You can also bulk load IAP products; http://help.apple.com/itc/appsspec/#/itc4df45cb20